# Amazon SWF workflow regularly increasing memory usage

Tags: amazon-swf

My application creates SWF workflows for a business process and each workflow finishes execution within reasonable time (within couple of seconds) without any timeouts. However the EC2 memory usage continuously keep going up with the number of workflows and ultimately the application falls over and starts giving '502 Bad Gateway', once the memory usage reaches a range of approx 900MB. I see a lot of SocketExceptions as below....

```
[2017-05-15 10:12:18.720] [ INFO] []: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:160)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:84)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:251)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:223)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:685)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:487)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:306)
```

What might be wrong? Please suggest what and where to check.

Comment: After analysing the data a bit more, I realised that the threads are not getting killed even after the workflow times out and thats causing the number of threads going up regularly. Can someone point me in the right direction and suggest what am I missing in the code/config that should be responsible for terminating these threads?

Comment: SWF uses thread pools, so it shouldn't lead threads. My guess is that your workflow activities make some external requests which leak these. From the exception it is not even clear which call it makes. Is it the complete thread stack?